# unable to enable php server 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, apache2, php

I can't get php to enable on my web server. There is no apache module to enable it. I have libapache2-mod-php and libapache-mod-php8.1 installed but there is no module to install it. How can I get it working?

ubuntu server 20.04, php 8.1.2, and apache 2.4.52

Php and libapache2-mod-php where both installed using synaptic

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you [edit] your question to include the steps you followed to get PHP installed on your system and what errors you might be seeing? Generally this can be enabled with an `a2enmod`, but there's not enough detail to know if this is what you're missing.

Comment: How are you enabling it?  Are you using `a2enmod php` or `a2enmod php8.1`?  If you don't run `a2enmod` on the proper modules it will not *load* the modules even if they're available

Comment: a2enmod php and a2enmod php8.1 both give the message "ERROR: module does not exist!"

Comment: I installed php via apt along with lib apache2-mod-php